# Зима-весна

Tags: орфография

Дефис или тире в сочетании "зима - весна"? И нужны ли пробелы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Написание зависит от значения. Если сочетание имеет значение приблизительного указания (то ли зимой, то ли весной), ставится дефис: *зима-весна*. Если же сочетание обозначает интервал значений («от... до»), ставится тире: *зимой — весной* (т. е. с начала зимы по конец весны).
**P.S.** Дефис - без пробелов, внутри слова; тире - в предложении, с пробелами.