# Дефис при приблизительном указании

Tags: дефис-тире

Смутила мысль из ответа Соан на [этот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13249/%D0%97%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0) вопрос:

> Если сочетание имеет значение приблизительного указания (то ли зимой, то ли весной), ставится дефис: **зима-весна.**

Автора спросить не получается, поэтому вопрос ко всем: вы сталкивались с подобным дефисным употреблением? Если да, то где можно найти правило об этом?

В Нацкорпусе подобных примеров не нашёл... нет! Нашёл-таки, написав раздельно, один на "зимой-весной" и порядочно на "весной-летом".

Похоже, Соан действительно права. Но хочется найти правило. Особенно буду рад, если оно рассматривает не только этот случай, но и похожие на него (сам не могу обобщить и понять, на что ещё можно его распространить).

И заодно вопрос: я правильно понимаю, что если указан чёткий интервал, не предположительный, то тогда может ставиться только тире, длинное или среднее, но не дефис?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: помню, вы тоже об этом упоминали, Римма. Не знаете, где правило об этом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**§ 118.**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=63#pp63) Следующие разряды слов пишутся через дефис.
5. Сочетания, имеющие значение приблизительного указания на количество или время чего-либо, например: *день-другой, неделя-другая, напишет письмо-другое, год-два, два-три часа, раза три-четыре, человек двенадцатъ-пятнадцатъ, двое-трое мальчиков, вдвоём-втроём; Он вернется **в марте-апреле.***
Примечание.
Если в таких конструкциях количество обозначается цифрами, между ними ставится не дефис, а тире, например: *человек 12 — 15; ей лет 30 — 35; рублей 200 — 300; это было году в 1950 — 1951-м.*

[**§ 154.**](http://orthographia.ru/orf.php?paragraph=pp154.php) В следующих случаях вместо дефиса должен употребляться знак тире.
4. В сочетаниях, имеющих значение приблизительного указания на количество или время чего-либо, если хотя бы одна из частей содержит пробел, например: *Приехал всего на день — на два. Он был в этом городе раз двадцать — двадцать пять. Это будет стоить двести — двести пятьдесят рублей. Она приедет в январе — начале февраля.* Ср.: *день-два, раз двадцать-тридцать, рублей двести-триста, **в январе-феврале.***

[**Вопрос № 285128**](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=285128)
Здравствуйте! Подскажите, тире с пробелами или без пробелов мы ставим в сочетании "март — май", "сентябрь — ноябрь"? Спасибо заранее!
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Если сочетание имеет значение приблизительного указания, ставится дефис, например: *в марте-апреле* («то ли в марте, то ли в апреле»). Если же сочетание обозначает интервал значений («от... до»), ставится тире, пробелы нужны: *в марте — апреле* (т. е. с каких-то чисел марта до каких-то чисел апреля), *в марте — мае* (с марта до мая).

...*персональный самолет Григория Речкалова, на котором он летал на заключительном этапе Великой Отечественной войны, **зима-весна** 1945 г.* (М. Быков. Самолеты советских асов. Боевая раскраска «сталинских соколов»)
[Фотография сделана или зимой, или весной.]

*Разумеется, разработку плана наш Генштаб мог и ускорить, но ранее зимы он не был бы готов, а зимой войну такого масштаба не начинают, так что все равно — **весна-лето** 1942 года* (М. Сетров. Воинствующая олигархия США против всего мира и нас).
[Начало войны планировалось на весну или лето.]

Comment: О, спасибо, Римма!