# "Из пальтишки" — так допустимо?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, падежи, одушевленность

Это из [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inhnC5Kjabk) на ютьюбе со встречи с Валентином Катаевым в 1978 году (II часть). Там он читает свой рассказ, и попадаются такие слова (в конце 28-й минуты): *обнаружилось, что я уже сильно вырос из своего матросского пальтишк**и**.*
 Не "из пальтишка", а, как будто одушевлённое, "из пальтишки". Что это: разговорный или диалектный вариант? Или просто ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно же, в словаре Ушакова род указан:
[ПАЛЬТИ́ШКО](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/919714), пальтишк**а**, мн. пальтишки, пальтишек, пальтишкам, **ср.** (*разг. фам. пренебр.*); уменьш. к пальто.

И правильно, конечно же, в родительном падеже — только [*пальтишк**а***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE).

Здесь, думаю, дело не в одушевленности. Просто произошла оговорка, потому что есть на **-ишко** похожие уменьшительные слова мужского рода (в некоторых из них допускается двоякое окончание в Р. п. ед. числа):
[**пиджачишко**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE) (*-а* и *-и*), чемоданишко (*-а* и *-и*), **кафтанишко** (*-а* и *-и*), сундучишко, рублишко.

Стоит отметить, что в тексте книги «Разбитая жизнь, или Волшебный рог Оберона» (1973 г. — **до** интервью) всё написано правильно.

> Папа и мама, весело ежась, засунули озябшие руки в рукава. Сидя между ними, я пытался сделать то же самое, но обнаружилось, что я уже вырос из своего [матросского пальтишк**а**](http://www.valentinkataev.ru/content/view/2003/479/) с золочеными дутыми пуговицами и мои руки не влезали в рукава, ставшие очень тесными, короткими.
>   . . .
>   Однажды недалеко от почтового ящика я увидел у стены дома на камнях плоский, как бы сделанный из полированного палисандрового дерева орех конского каштана и тут же подобрал его и положил в карманчик своего [матросского пальтишк**а**](http://www.valentinkataev.ru/content/view/2150/479/) как величайшую драгоценность.

В дополнение

В русский язык слово «пальто» попало только во второй четверти XIX в.
В словаре В. И. Даля (1863—1866): **пальто** — ср. несклон. франц. весьма неудобное для нас названье верхнего платья, мужского и женского в роде широкого сертука; чапан.

У А. П. Чехова новомодное слово «пальтишко» употреблено в женском роде («Степь», 1888):
*Теперь ему казалось, что небо было близко к нему, а земля далеко.

— Эй, возьми **свою пальтишку**! — крикнул где-то далеко внизу Дениска.*

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! А вы по тому вопросу не прокомментируете, где я к вам обратился?

Comment: Извините, Артем, чегой-то я пропустила-запамятовала, наверно. Напомните, пожалуйста. Сейчас _родной народ_ к праздникам (со всех сторон!) подтянулся, времени — в обрез.

Comment: Вот ссылка: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/456861/%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8#comment470159_456861.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ушакова приводится как вариант "пальтишка", но род не указывается, - неясно, как употребить такое слово в контексте, где род проявляет себя, например в сочетании с местоимением. Поскольку "*свой пальтишка*" или "*своё пальтишка*" не говорят (в отличие от вариантных "этот *городишка*, *домишка*" - где род не варьируется), то можно рассматривать "своего пальтишки" как небольшую *оговорку*.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Answer (score 1):

Склонение существительных мужского и среднего с суффиксом ИШК, вероятно, не сразу было закреплено в правилах, поэтому в текстах до сих пор можно встретить **отклонения от существующей нормы**: *мой домишка, из моего домишки, его  пальтишко, из своего пальтишки* и т.д.

Причем это касается **не только старых, но и современных текстов,** и тогда делается вполне намеренно. Вероятно, стилевая характеристика этих форм всё-таки различна.

Например:

Тогда баскетбольного роста парнюга, находящийся уже внутри, схватил ручищами Ильи Муромца застрявшего в дверях жонглера **за ворот его детского пальтишки** ...[Евгений Евтушенко. «Волчий паспорт» (1999)]

А рядом  -  мальчонка лет десяти. Воротник **его старенького пальтишки** был поднят.https://www.proza.ru/2016/03/24/562

Намеднись наехали на наш Бугуруслан сто калмыков со своим старшиной, Фомою Алексеевым, разграбили все обывательские домы, и **мой домишка** претерпел...[В. Я. Шишков. Емельян Пугачев. Книга вторая. Ч. 1-2 (1939-1945)]

Остановившись, я попытался мысленно сориентироваться, сообразить, где я сейчас нахожусь ― относительно входа, гребня холмов и **моего домишки.**..[Юрий Буйда. Щина // «Знамя», 2000]

Comment: С домишкой или городишкой (даже у Чехова встречается) проще: там род не меняется при склонении и остаётся мужским. А у нас из  среднего в женский превращается при местоимении ср./м. рода.

Comment: ... вырос из своего матросского пальтишки. Здесь мужской род, не женский.

Comment: Т. е. в именительном "свой матросский пальтишка"? Совсем странно звучит. У Риммы в лит. примере женский род (своей).

Comment: Я думаю, что окончания такие: свое пальтишко - своего пальтишки - своим пальтишком.   Только Р.п имеет окончание И, а не А.

Comment: Тогда такое окончание не подчиняется общим схемам (единственное в своём роде), и вместо склонения слово среднего рода нужно помнить сразу в двух падежах, либо полагать, что род слова "пальтишко"  одном из падежей меняется со среднего на мужской (чего не бывает с другими словами), поскольку так склоняются слова м. р. "городишко" и "городишка", а для пальтишк(...) именительный падеж явно соотв. ср. роду (если не женскому).

Comment: Вы допускаете "св**ой** пальтишко(-а)"?

Comment: Род во всех словах средний, просто используется окончание И вместо А в Р.п. Мне, к примеру, окончание А после уменьшительно-ласкательного суффикса ИШК как-то не очень "ласкает" слух и кажется грубым. И вообще, я же привела примеры, взятые из вполне приличных текстов, в которых  используется форма "своего пальтишки".  Почему?  Есть же какая-то причина.  И ведь это современные тексты!