# Друг у меня (–) лингвист

Tags: пунктуация, тире, разговорная-речь

Обязательно ли тире между подлежащим и сказуемым в этом случае?

`Друг у меня – лингвист.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотите сделать два ударения и обозначить паузу – ставьте тире:
*Др**У**г у меня – лингв**И**ст.*

Если делаете ударение только на сказуемом или только на подлежащем, то тире не нужно:
*Друг у меня лингв**И**ст.* // *Др**У**г у меня лингвист.*

[**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91) (справочник Розенталя, пункт 1):

> **Примечание.** Обычно тире не ставится:
> **1)** в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля речи:
> *Моя **мать инженер**; Мой **брат школьник***.

Comment: У вас в примерах уже реверс слов. Брат мой школьник, мать моя женщина.

Comment: @Буратино Не у меня в примерах. Я взял только исходное предложение. // Я ушёл, до завтра.

Answer (score 2):

Расстановка ударений зависит от **текста**.

(1) *Надо у друга спросить. **ДрУг** у меня – лингвИст.*

Ударение на подлежащем, пауза и тире.

(2) *Надо бы у друга спросить. Друг у меня **лингвИст**, но он сейчас в командирОвке.*

Ударение на сказуемом, нет паузы и тире.

**Примечание.**  Я не думаю, что надо ориентироваться на стиль речи. В любом стиле важен именно контекст.

**[ПАС под ред.Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106)**

**Примечание.** Тире может не ставиться, если в письменной речи отражено произношение **с логическим ударением на сказуемом:** Моя сестра учительница (ср.: Моя сестра — учительница — ударение и на слове сестра, и на слове учительница). Тире обязательно: 1) если имеется сопоставление: Моя сестра — учительница, а брат — зоотехник; 2) если возможна синтаксическая или смысловая двусмысленность; ср.: Брат — мой учитель и Брат мой — учитель.

Comment: Sharon, в своём ответе я ориентируюсь не на стиль речи, а на единственный пункт правил, допускающий отсутствие тире, когда между главными членами (существительными) нет других компонентов: частиц, вводных слов, наречий и др.

Comment: А вы из простого предложения сделали сложное. Разве без части с союзом "но" нельзя обойтись без тире?

Comment: В своем ответе   я добавила правило Лопатина, оно как раз о логических ударениях.  Предложение можно добавить любое,  с союзом НО или без него, это не имеет никакого значения. Я добавляю подходящий контекст.

Comment: Это хорошо, оно не противоречит Розенталю и моему ответу, а дополняет.

Comment: Александр, а  я разве критикую ваш ответ. Под ответом нельзя вроде бы писать критику)  Я вообще стараюсь никого не комментировать, если только хвалю и восхищаюсь.  Или вам вообще не нравится, что  отвечаю?)   Неужели ничего нового не сказала? А честно говоря, меня  удивил ваш подход в ответе: хотите – не хотите.

Comment: Критику писать можно и нужно. Мне ваш ответ нравится, кроме добавки к исходному предложению. "Хотите" = "если автор хочет" = "если так задумано".

Comment: Если автор что-то задумал, он выберет соответствующую структуру, а без этого мы не узнаем, что он задумал.  Добавка не понравилась? А как без нее, мне же нужно, чтобы ударение однозначно перешло на конец предложения. Я других способов, кроме сложного предложения, не знаю. А вы что предложите? (А критику никто не любит,  лукавят люди.)

Comment: Я уже предложил автору самому выбрать. Правила допускают оба варианта. В примерах Розенталя простые предложения, никакой другой структуры не требуется, чтобы не ставить тире.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, оно мне показалось интересным. Ваши взгляды меняются, но это нормально...  Вот только в какую сторону вы идете. не могу понять.  Когда-то мы думали примерно одинаково, Да вроде бы совсем недавно, пары месяцев не прошло.

Comment: А кстати, не подскажете? Друг у меня – лингвист.   У меня друг – лингвист. Мой друг – лингвист. Почему из трех возможных вариантов  автор выбрал именно первый?  Это ведь тоже его выбор (правда, скорее интуитивный). Есть ли разница?

Comment: Sharon, почему – надо спрашивать у Леопольда-мэтра, но все варианты могут быть как с тире, так и без (это будет определяться его контекстом и его акцентами). // Я никуда не иду, я с вами :)) // А если бы вы не упомянули о стиле речи, то вообще этот разговор не состоялся бы (я просто скопировал примечание из Розенталя).

Comment: Спасибо!!  Эмоции правят нами, увы.  На мой вопрос вот не отвечает... Опять хочу/не хочу... А еще этот Розенталь со своим разговорным стилем (терпеть не могу это правило)!..  А дальше действия. Извините...

Comment: А предложение с инверсией, как мне кажется. А это обычно повод для тире. Можно ли его в каком-то тексте использовать без тире, вот что интересно.

Comment: "Откуда ты это знаешь? Ты лингвист?" – "Нет, дрУг у меня лингвист".

Comment: Ага, контекст! И предложение осложненное, хотя можно без "нет".  А сразу привести?))  И еще пример с тире, пжста.  Хочется историю про друга-лингвиста послушать.

Comment: "Откуда ты это знаешь? – "Друг у меня – лингвист. Вот и поправляет меня на каждом шагу: то кофе у него мужского рода, то "не одену, а надену", а с ударениями ваще засада!" // А по поводу контекста, помните, уже переписывались с вами. Зачем выдумывать за автора, пусть сам свой текст анализирует (после того как мы ему правило нашли и "разрешили своевольничать").

Comment: Да уж, с лингвистами беда!  Среднее кофе я тоже пить не буду,  а вот пальтишку могу одеть. А чё? //  "ДрУг у меня лингвист", А может все-таки без тире?  //  Автор хочет научиться правильно выдумывать. Надо сказать: контекст и ударения!  Я как раз и вспомнила это противостояние.. Кстати, тогда автор принесла свой контекст, и все стало ясно.

Answer (score 1):

Мать моя женщина, но друг у меня лингвист все-таки.

Я позаимствую примеры ваши-с:

*Надо у друга спросить, потому что друг у меня – лингвист.* = надо спросить у друга, а друг = лингвист =>  надо спросить у лингвиста.

**А** друг - лингвист - скорее всего нужна будет тирешечка.

*Друг у меня лингвист, но он сейчас в командировке.*=*Мой друг лингвист сейчас в командировке.* - не лингвист в командировке, а друг в командировке, **но** друг лингвист.

*У меня* как придаток не везде звучит органично.

Comment: Очень смешной рассказ про друга-лингвиста.  Но вот тема эта (приложения) довольно-таки сложная. Есть разрешенные в грамматике формы, их и надо применять. Но сначала надо определиться с содержанием: о чем рассказать хотите в своем повествовании о нелегкой жизни лингвиста.

Comment: А вообще говоря, юмора на форуме не хватает. Жизнь и так серьезная, люди морально устали, а хочется отдохнуть и расслабиться. Все чаще вижу такие записи: неохота отвечать; лень; может, завтра/вечером отвечу.

Comment: Давно заметил и хотел спросить, почему у вас тире женского рода?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец не задумывался). Тире — (франц. tiret — черточка)(это я не к тому, что я прям французский знаю). Запятая, точка - женского, тире тоже), может быть *постановка* тире нужна.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец хотя я же не говорю, нужна будет пальто, наверное, это ошибка. Хотя, вот нужно будет пюре, но нужна будет пюрешка. Вообще тире как название элемента у меня не держится в голове видимо.) Буква, литера, кавычка - все женского, иногда мужского - дефис, знак, а тире вдруг среднего, как кофе. Или кофе уже мужской? Ну на мужской тире вроде тоже не тянет.

Comment: Кофе из мужского хочет в средний перебраться :). Язык тяготеет к своим правилам, привычным окончаниям...

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Тогда могу писать кофий и тирешечка.

Comment: Тирёшечка или терешечка? Л. любит букву Ё))

Comment: без ё, тирешечка, браузер еще находит дефисик. Кстати дефисик сохраняет мужской род, а вот пальтишечко - все равно не переделывается в женский или мужской, как и деревце.

Comment: Вот плохо, что Ё не обозначают.  Пару точек трудно поставить?

Comment: не ровен час, тире будет женского рода!

Comment: Оно у вас и так  по-женски склоняется (тирешечка), немного осталось.   Пора этот м. род потеснить.

Comment: Действительно, а то одни авторки и директорки. И не только мужской, средний тоже потеснить пора. Шире шагай феминизм!

Comment: Еще "ширше" надо! А разве не было никогда слова "пальтишка"?    См. предновогодний диспут https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457490/Из-пальтишки-так-допустимо

Comment: Так проблема в том, что средний тяготеет к мужскому, о среднем же говорят о нём, а не о ней. Вот и просклонял Катаев в мужском роде:  своего матросского пальтишки, - а не своей матросской пальтишки. Не в окончании дело, а в согласовании же) а я согласовал через женский)

Comment: @Sharon  Или вы думали, что тирешечка это он?) я думал, пюре- пюрешечка, тире - тирешечка.

Comment: А Чехов?  Эй, возьми свою пальтишку! — крикнул где-то далеко внизу Дениска.  Тирешечка ни то ни се, поэтому ср.род.